# Is it correct to say "I bought 2 sets of 3 bunk beds"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

Normally, we just have a unit of bunk beds that has just 2 beds that look like this. Is it correct to say "**I have a pair of bunk beds**" or "**I have a set of 2 bunk beds**"?

[image]

..............
Also,

**What if the whole unit has more than 2 bunk beds?**

Is this whole thing called "**a set of 3 bunk beds**"?
[image]

Comment: You could buy any number of sets of two or three bunk beds. Bunk beds are two beds, one on top of another. You don't say: I have two twin sisters, do you?

Comment: If you say you've got a couple of [***triple bunk beds***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=triple+bunk+bed%2Cthree-tier+bunk+bed%2C3-tier+bunk+bed&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3), people will understand that you have beds for up to 6 people (but possibly only if they're *children*).

Comment: During an overnight train journey to a ski resort in the Pyrenees, my wife and I shared a compartment with two other couples, three bunks high either side of the compartment. It required some negotiation to decide who was to sleep where, and there was no possibility of sitting  up.

Answer (score 2):

No. The first shows a bunk-bed.  No modification is required. By default a bunk bed has two levels.

The second also shows a bunk-bed, but the three levels is rather rare and could be specified as a "triple-decker bunk bed".

So you could say I bought "two triple-decker bunk-beds"

I'd probably also understand "a triple bunk-bed" and that might be preferred by some. But this is a rare item with no universally accepted name, but one which is formed by analogy.

My analogy is from buses which (where I live) are often "double-decker", hence "triple-decker" is natural.

Comment: You wouldn't just call it a triple bunk bed?  I think most people would intuitively know what that means.

Comment: I think I'd understand that, but "double-decker" and hence "triple-decker" are very common, especially where the buses are generally double-deckers.

Comment: In America, we don't have double decker buses but we do have double and triple decker sandwiches. The phrasing would be understood here too.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be absolutely clear, you can use the word *quantity*.

"I got triple bunk beds, quantity 2."

"I want to buy quantity 2 of the bunk beds."

It's somewhat clunky, but it is used when one needs to be absolutely clear, such as when making a business transaction.